# How to keep a specific user signed in forever

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, angular, authentication

I have an angular client that gets authenticated in the backend, when a user is authenticated the client receives an access token and a refresh token, the access token expires in 1 hour, the refresh token expires in 48 hours.

I want to set the default refresh token to 48 hours but I want one specific user to have a refresh token of 100 days, is there a way to achieve this?

My Angular Client uses: oidc-token-manager

My backend server uses: Identity Server 3

Comment: Is it even possible? Any help? I just want one specific user to be signed in forever (or at least 100 days)...

Comment: I suggest handling this at the time you are setting the refresh token expiration time in the server. If the current user exists on your special users table or something similar then change the refresh token expiration time to 100 days.

Comment: Maybe this cal help you via BE: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/857 and since you pass the username to the auth function, you can simply do `if(user == "something")` and execute the logic. But I think there is a better way